# Calculate LRC in Objective c

Tags: objective-c

I want to calculate the LRC of a message that I send via Bluetooth. Here is for example a message :

(The message structure is STX MESSAGE FS EXT LRC)

02 1212004123422826E0B8C0F000F0A00182620000THYRON SYSTEMS WATFORD UKR 1C 03 60

```
STX = 02
MESSAGE = 1212004123422826E0B8C0F000F0A00182620000THYRON SYSTEMS WATFORD UKR
FS = 1C
EXT = 03
LRC = 60
```

What I have to do is calculate the LRC by performing a modulo 2 binary sum of every character in the communication message excluding the STX character but including the EXT characterr.

Before to calculate the LRC, I have to convert this NSString in HexaString :

31323132 30303431 32333432 32383236 45304238 43304630 30304630 41303031 38323632 30303030 54485952 4f4e2053 59535445 4d532057 4154464f 52442055 4b521c03

Method used :

```
- (NSString *) stringToHex:(NSString *)str
{   
    NSUInteger len = [str length];
    unichar *chars = malloc(len * sizeof(unichar));
    [str getCharacters:chars];

    NSMutableString *hexString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < len; i++ )
    {
        [hexString appendFormat:@"%02x", chars[i]];
    }
    free(chars);

    return [hexString autorelease];
}
```

And then I have to convert it in Byte Array.
Method used :

```
- (NSData*) hexToBytes:(NSString *) hexaStr {

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData data];
    int idx;
    for (idx = 0; idx+2 <= hexaStr.length; idx+=2) {
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(idx, 2);
        NSString * hexStrTmp = [hexaStr substringWithRange:range];
        NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexStrTmp];
        unsigned int intValue;
        [scanner scanHexInt:&intValue];
        [data appendBytes:&intValue length:1];
    }
    return data;
}
```

And then I try to do calculate my LRC, that should be 60, with the following :

```
- (void) calculateLRC:(NSString *) text {

    NSData * data = [self hexToBytes:text];

    NSUInteger size = [data length] / sizeof(const char);
    const char * array = (const char*) [data bytes];

    char checksum = 0;

    for( uint32_t i = 0 ; i < size; i++) {

        checksum += * array++;
    }

    NSLog(@"Checksum = %c", checksum);

    self.LRC_Check = checksum;
}
```

The problem is that "checksum" has not the value "60" in it. Can someone help me with that please ?

Thanx in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the answer !

In the method `- (void) calculateLRC:(NSString *) text` I have to replace :

```
checksum += * array++;
```

with :

```
checksum ^= * array++;
```

I thougt the Modulo character was "%" in Objective C...

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this in swift

this seems to work . .need to do some rigorous testing though..

```
var str = computeLRC(hexString:"373203")
print(str)
```

// returns 06

```
func computeLRC (hexString: String ) -> String {
    var checksum : UInt16 = 0
    var my = ""
    for i in stride(from: 0, to: hexString.count, by: 2) {
        
        let indexStartOfText = hexString.index( hexString.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
        let indexEndOfText = hexString.index( indexStartOfText, offsetBy: 2)
        let substring3 = hexString[indexStartOfText..<indexEndOfText]
        
        let intResult =  Int(String(substring3) , radix: 16)
        guard let myUnicodeScalar = UnicodeScalar(intResult!) else {
            return ""
        }
        // convert UnicodeScalar to Character
        let myCharacter = Character(myUnicodeScalar)
        
        my += String(myCharacter)
    }
    
    for myChar in my {
        var byte: UInt16 = Array(String(myChar).utf16)[0]
        checksum ^= byte
    }
    
    return String(format:"%02X", checksum)
    
}
```