# Convert C# to swift : LRC when doing primitive serial communication

Tags: swift, serial-port

I need equivalent swift 4.2 code for my existing C# code.
I have a C# app which communicates with a verifone card reader.
I always Append a BYTE after each instruction for LRC  . 
I am including my C# code. ( notice it has XOR operation )

here is an example instruction to reset the verifone ( in hex )

0237320306 which translates to  STX-3732-ETX-LRC

to compute LRC. , you send everything between STX and LRC --> 373203
the answer is of course is  06

// here is working C# code

```
private string GetChecksum(string s)
  {
    int checksum = 0;
    foreach (char c in GetStringFromHex(s))
      {
         checksum ^= Convert.ToByte(c);
      }
      return checksum.ToString("X2");
 } 
private string GetStringFromHex(string s)
 {
   string result = "";
   string s2 = s.Replace(" ", "");
   for (int i = 0; i < s2.Length; i += 2)
     {
       result += Convert.ToChar(int.Parse(s2.Substring(i, 2),   System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
     }
     return result;
}
```

/// I found some code for objective C but I don't know if it works and I really am new to the apple world so I want to stick to SWIFT

[Calculate LRC in Objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512071/calculate-lrc-in-objective-c)

please help me write this code in swift 4.2

Comment: Please show what you have done till now. Some C# methods you have successfully converted, with the converted Swift methods. Do-everything-for-me questions are not welcome in this site.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work . .need to do some rigorous testing though..

```
var str = computeLRC(hexString:"373203")
print(str)
```

// returns 06

'''

```
func computeLRC (hexString: String ) -> String {
    var checksum : UInt16 = 0
    var my = ""
    for i in stride(from: 0, to: hexString.count, by: 2) {

        let indexStartOfText = hexString.index( hexString.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
        let indexEndOfText = hexString.index( indexStartOfText, offsetBy: 2)
        let substring3 = hexString[indexStartOfText..<indexEndOfText]

        let intResult =  Int(String(substring3) , radix: 16)
        guard let myUnicodeScalar = UnicodeScalar(intResult!) else {
            return ""
        }
        // convert UnicodeScalar to Character
        let myCharacter = Character(myUnicodeScalar)

        my += String(myCharacter)
    }

    for myChar in my {
        var byte: UInt16 = Array(String(myChar).utf16)[0]
        checksum ^= byte
    }

    return String(format:"%02X", checksum)

}
```

'''